# Question about GC and event handlers

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Timer, event and garbage collection : am I missing something ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311027/timer-event-and-garbage-collection-am-i-missing-something)

If I'd have the following code:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Start();
}
```

will `timer_Tick` continue to be repeatedly called after the `SomeMethod` has finished even though there is no reference to the timer anywhere?

I'm thinking maybe it will until the Timer's Dispose method is called. But then, in general, does the GC knows when an object have not been disposed?

Comment: Only `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or `System.Web.UI` have a `Tick`.

Comment: Does it matter? `System.Windows.Form.Timer`. But I'm just using it as a sample. I want to know in general how this works.

Comment: I believe it is System.Windows.Forms.Timer as this is the only one with an event named Tick. (afaik)

Comment: GC knows about all managed objects.

Comment: @Henk But this question is not a duplicate of the proposed one. The proposed one is about DispatcherTimer, this question here doesn't use that. I too believe that this question has been asked before, but we should at least find a *correct* duplicate before it is closed as such.

Comment: @Lasse: The OP said it didn't matter which timer... And as long as there's no specific Timer here you can't find an exact dupe. I suggest NARQ.

Comment: In general, I agree, because all the timers behave differently, so there is no way to answer *that* question. Still, since he said one of them specifically in a comment, I closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @jsoldi Please don't reask in general about all the timers, they all behave differently, so if you do ask that question, it will be closed as not-a-real-question, as @Henk says. Since you specifically mentioned the System.Windows.Forms one, I closed your question as a duplicate of one answering for that timer. There are other questions here with answers for the other timers as well, at least DispatcherTimer has one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to the other answers here, no, the timer will not be garbage collected.

Internally, enabling the timer will allocate a `GCHandle` object, which will keep the object, and thus the timer, and thus whatever object has the implementing event handler(s) alive until you disable it, or the program ends, whichever comes first.

This has already been answered here on SO, [here: Timer, event and garbage collection : am I missing something ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311027/timer-event-and-garbage-collection-am-i-missing-something), so I'm going to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

No code anywhere will be holding a reference to `timer`; therefore it will be eligible for garbage collection.

The `timer` object *itself* has a reference to your `timer_Tick` method, but that doesn't matter. It can still be collected.

Comment: Which won't necessarily just stop the timer but possibly cause an exception depending on how the `Timer` is designed. This kinda sucks about managed garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

The GC will collect it at his next crawl... It is like any other object.
The timer is referencing to the event, not the event to the instance, so it will be GC'd.