# Lambda closure lifetime and timer handlers

Tags: c#, timer, lambda, garbage-collection

I normally avoid using local variables to hold references to timers because when the local variable goes out of scope the timer gets garbage collected and stops firing.  However, I ran into a bit of code that seems to get around this problem by referencing the timer itself through a closure in a lambda expression that is attached to the `Elapsed` event.

```
{
    var bkgTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(timeDelay) {AutoReset = false};
    bkgTimer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => Handler(e, bkgTimer);
    bkgTimer.Start();
}
```

Then later, in the Handler:

```
private void Handler( ... timer)
{
    ...
    timer.Dispose();
}
```

It appears to work.  Are there any problems with this approach?  I wondered if it could lead to a memory leak since I don't understand what the lifetime of the lambda closure is controlled by.

Comment: This may be your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311027/timer-event-and-garbage-collection-am-i-missing-something. Thomas demonstrates how the Timer holds a reference to itself.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens : That's a Forms.Timer. This is about a Timers.Timer.

Comment: There is a Timer class mixup in this question too, it is System.Threading.Timer that has the GC problem, not System.Timers.Timer.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the difference, is there a link you can post on the topic?

Comment: Here it is explained in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962172/why-does-a-system-timers-timer-survive-gc-but-not-system-threading-timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object cannot avoid GC simply by referencing itself — that's the key distinction between true garbage collectors and reference-counting techniques. If the GC cannot reach it from a root, it will collect it.

Call [`GCHandle.Alloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a95009h1.aspx) to prevent collection, and call [`GCHandle.Free`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.free.aspx) in the `Handler` method to prevent leakage.

The advice in the documentation to use [`GC.KeepAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx) only applies to long-running methods. If the method exits immediately, as yours appears to do, `GC.KeepAlive` won't have the desired effect.

Incidentally, you shouldn't need a separate handler method:

```
var bkgTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(timeDelay) {AutoReset = false};
var timerHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(bkgTimer);
bkgTimer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => {
    …
    timerHandle.Free();
    bkgTimer.Dispose();
};

bkgTimer.Start();
```