# How to implement setInterval(js) in C#

Tags: c#

JS's setInterval and setTimeOut is really convenient. And I want to ask how to implement the same thing in C#.

Comment: You can use a `Timer` Class, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx

Comment: An explanation of the actual problem you're trying to solve would help understand which possible alternative you could use in C#, or even if the problem lends itself to be solved using this type of approach.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can't. C# *by itself* cannot do any of the sorts. However, if you're talking about .NET, then there are at least 3 Timer classes: [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) and [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen There is another one `System.Web.UI.Timer` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can just do a `Task.Delay` within a `Task.Run`, try out:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => {
                        for(;;)
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(10000)
                            Console.WriteLine("Hello World after 10 seconds")
                        }
                    });
```

Then You could even wrap this up in to your own SetInterval method that takes in an action

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetInterval(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello World"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        SetInterval(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello Stackoverflow"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));


        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }

    public static async Task SetInterval(Action action, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        await Task.Delay(timeout).ConfigureAwait(false);

        action();

        SetInterval(action, timeout);
    }
}
```

or you could just use the built in Timer class which practically does the same thing

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var timer1 = new Timer(_ => Console.WriteLine("Hello World"), null, 0, 2000);
        var timer2 = new Timer(_ => Console.WriteLine("Hello Stackoverflow"), null, 0, 4000);


        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }
```

Just make sure you're timers don't go out of scope and get disposed.

**.NET 6 Update**

.NET 6 introduced a new type called `PeriodicTimer` this simplifies the above, and can be used like the following:

```cs
var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World after 10 seconds")
}
```

If you need to be able to cancel the timer the `WaitForNextTickAsync` function has an overload for
a cancellation token.

Comment: As I correct understand correctly this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2311184/647845 timer won't get disposed when it goes out of scope?

Comment: @DirkBoer that's correct, alternatively just keep a reference to it alive

Comment: ahh okay! Good to get double confirmed. Shouldn't the last sentence be changed in this answer then? :) saves people maybe a second lookup for the ones that are doubting.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `for(;;)` for loop here?

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace it just the same as writing `while(true)`

Comment: @KevinSmith - Thanks.  I thought that was probably the intent.  Why not just use while(true)?  heh

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace no idea... just preference... fewer keyboard presses 

Answer (score 4):

Its simply like this, you define an static System.Timers.Timer; then call the function that binds the timer.Elapsed event to your interval function that will be called each X miliseconds.

```
   public class StaticCache {        
      private static System.Timers.Timer syncTimer;

      StaticCache(){
        SetSyncTimer();
      }
      private void SetSyncTimer(){
        // Create a timer with a five second interval.
        syncTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        syncTimer.Elapsed += SynchronizeCache;
        syncTimer.AutoReset = true;
        syncTimer.Enabled = true;
     }
     private static void SynchronizeCache(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
        // do this stuff each 5 seconds
     }
    }
```