# Include timer to packman

Tags: c#, console, 2d-games

I am creating my own game - packman. I am using C# console. I have got all function expect ghost moving. Now they change position when I press button. I would like to change their position after 0.5 sec. I try some functions like this: [How to implement setInterval(js) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081305/how-to-implement-setintervaljs-in-c-sharp) but it doesn t work. Have you got any idea to move ghost after 0.5 secs? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why doesn't it work ? what happens ? Show us the code that you tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(MoveGhost);
timer.Interval = 500; // 0.5 sec
timer.Start();
```

Place it in the main function. This should do it.

Comment: Ok that's great idea. But how can I refresh console? My map is printing when I press any button. Do you have an idea to resolve that problem?

Comment: Just create a function that calls Console.Clear() and then draws the gaming board. Then you can just throw this function into a new timer. Otherwise if you have a while loop, you can just call Console.Clear() and DrawGame every single iteration of the loop