# How to Run method after every 5 sec in while loop using c#

Tags: c#

I have a condition in my project where I have to hit an API after every 5 secs.

```
while(true)
{
    // here I have to call the method after every 5 secs
    method();
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't usually do this in a loop, use a timer instead.

Comment: yeah, you must not use a loop for such cases, timer is a good solution. Have a look [How to implement setInterval(js) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41081355/6901693)

Answer (score 1):

As I already has been said, use a Timer instead. ie:

```
void Main()
{
  var t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000){Enabled = true};
  t.Elapsed += (sender, args) => { 
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
  };
}
```

EDIT: Example of a progress bar counting 30 (30000 millis) seconds.

```
void Main()
{
  Form f = new Form();
  ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar { Maximum=30000, Left=10, Top=10, Width=200 };
  Label l = new Label {Top=50,Left=10,Text=""};
  
  var t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000){Enabled = false};
  
  f.Controls.Add( pb );
  f.Controls.Add( l );
  
  f.Show();

  var start = DateTime.Now;
  t.Elapsed += (sender, args) => { 
      var elapsed = (int)(DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
      pb.Value=Math.Min(elapsed, pb.Maximum); 
      l.Text = (elapsed/1000).ToString();

      if (elapsed >= pb.Maximum)
      {
        t.Enabled = false;
      }
  };
  t.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you give some explanation of it ?

Comment: @RabnerCasandara, it simply initializes a system timer, that is running every 1000 milliseconds, and when it does, its Elapsed event is invoked. In Elapsed you can call your method, I simply output current datetime to console.  Your other code can continue to run, this would fire once a second (initialized with an Interval of 1000 milliseconds). In your case you would initialize with 5000. As an example I am adding a progressbar on a form.